# Receive an object including a list/array of objects in ksoap2(Android) from an AXIS2 WebService

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

i hope somebody can help me because this problem takes a lot of time and i dont know the solution. thx a lot in advance ...
I try to call my AXIS2-Webservice which returns a Object like this:

```
public class TestObject{

private int zahl = 1;
private String name = "test";
SecondObject sec_object = new SecondObject("eins");
List <SecondObject> obj_list = new ArrayList<SecondObject>();
static SecondObject [] array;

public TestObject(){
    obj_list.add(new SecondObject("zwei"));
    obj_list.add(new SecondObject("drei"));
    array = obj_list.toArray(new SecondObject[2]); }
    //getter & setter

public class SecondObject {

private String wert;

public SecondObject(String wert) {
    this.wert = wert;
}
```

From Android I call this like:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

int count = response.getPropertyCount();
        Log.v(TAG, "count :"+count);
        for (int y = 0; y < count; y++){
            if (response.getProperty(y)instanceof SoapObject){
                SoapObject sobj = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(y);
                Log.v(TAG, "soapOBJ "+sobj);
                Log.v(TAG, "count "+sobj.getPropertyCount());
                if (sobj.getProperty(0)!= null){
                    Log.v(TAG, "!=NULL"+sobj.getProperty(0)+"");
                }   
            }
        }

SoapObject array = (SoapObject) response.getProperty("array");
Log.v(TAG, "array "+array);
```

I saw a lot of posts, which call only an array of objects. In this case, I would like to call an object including an array of objects ... The problem is: array contains only one element, See this log:

```
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): count :7
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): soapOBJ SecondObject{wert=zwei; }
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): count 1
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): !=NULLzwei
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): soapOBJ SecondObject{wert=drei; }
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): count 1
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): !=NULLdrei
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): soapOBJ SecondObject{wert=zwei; }
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): count 1
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): !=NULLzwei
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): soapOBJ SecondObject{wert=drei; }
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): count 1
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): !=NULLdrei
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): soapOBJ SecondObject{wert=eins; }
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): count 1
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): !=NULLeins
09-05 14:58:31.120: V/ASYNCTASK(9314): array SecondObject{wert=zwei; }
```

Comment: sometimes people don't know the answer, or its a lot of work to come up with a solution. And sometimes its because of the quality of the question. If you found an answer to your problem post it below, and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get individual nodes from your top-level `SoapObject` as follows:

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
String name =  response.getPrimitivePropertySafelyAsString(NODE_NAME_FOR_NAME /* e.g. "name"? */);
int zahl = Integer.parseInt(response.getPrimitivePropertySafelyAsString(NODE_NAME_FOR_ZAHL /* e.g. "zahl"? */));
SoapObject obj_list = (SoapObject) response.getPropertySafely("obj_list");
for (int idx = 0; idx < obj_list.getPropertyCount(); idx++) {
    SoapObject secondObject = (SoapObject) forecastResultsNode.getProperty(idx);

    String wert=  forecastNode.getPrimitivePropertySafelyAsString("wert");
}
```

It would be good if you can post a snippet of the actual SOAP response (in XML) so I can provide a more specific answer.

An example of parsing a response similar to the structure you described can be found in [this blog article](http://thiranjith.com/2012/10/15/introduction-to-working-with-ksoap2-in-android/#process-service-response).